# Golang Rethinkdb nested filter

Tags: go, rethinkdb, gorethink, rethinkdb-go

I am trying to run a filter on a property of a nested object for RethinkDB in Golang. But I am sure that I am missing something here.

This is the error I am getting:

> (func literal).Eq undefined (type func(gorethink.Term) gorethink.Term has no field or method Eq)

Here is my code:

```
type User struct {
    Id        string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName,omitempty"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastName,omitempty"`
    Email     string `json:"email,omitempty"`
    Password  string `json:"password,omitempty"`
    Salt      string `json:"salt,omitempty"`
}

type UnverifiedUserRequest struct {
    Id    string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Token string `json:"token,omitempty"`
    User  User   `json:"user,omitempty"`
}

db.Table("unverified_requests").Filter(func(row r.Term) r.Term {
    return row.Field("user").Map(func(user r.Term) r.Term {
        return user.Field("email")
    }.Eq(email))
}).Run(session)
```

---

### UPDATE 1

After making changes as suggested by @icza, the program builds fine. But I am getting the following error at runtime:

> gorethink: Cannot convert OBJECT to SEQUENCE in: r.DB("uc_dev").Table("unverified_requests").Filter(func(var_‌​5 r.Term) r.Term { return var_5.Field("user").Map(func(var_6 r.Term) r.Term { return var_6.Field("email") }).Eq("myemail@gmail.com") })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A misplaced parenthesis. Instead of `}.Eq(email))` use `}).Eq(email)`:

```
db.Table("unverified_requests").Filter(func(row r.Term) r.Term {
    return row.Field("user").Map(func(user r.Term) r.Term {
        return user.Field("email")
    }).Eq(email)
}).Run(session)
```

You tried to call `Eq()` on the function literal argument that is passed to `Map()`. It is obviously not of type [`gorethink.Term`](https://godoc.org/github.com/GoRethink/gorethink#Term), but the return value of [`gorethink.Map()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/GoRethink/gorethink#Map) is, so call `Eq()` on the reutrn value of `Map()`, which means put the `.Eq()` after the parenthesis that closes the method call `Map()`.

Comment: I tried it. But now I get this error when I run it:

`gorethink: Cannot convert OBJECT to SEQUENCE in:
r.DB("uc_dev").Table("unverified_requests").Filter(func(var_5 r.Term) r.Term { return var_5.Field("user").Map(func(var_6 r.Term) r.Term { return var_6.Field("email") }).Eq("myemail@gmail.com") })`